# marking parameter costmap_2d

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a very brief question regarding the `marking` parameter in the *observation_sources* tag. To be more precise, let's suppose that I set `marking: false` for my laser_scan in the obstacle_layer, then my local costmap will be no longer updated with the laser readings, but what about the motion planner in `move_base`? Will move_base take into account those readings to plan locally or is it going to ignore them (so basically setting `marking: false` will be equivalent to remove the  obstacle_layer)?

Thanks and regards,
Federico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174993/marking-parameter-costmap_2d/) by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Costmaps, planners, etc are all fairly decoupled, the planners don't need to know how to update a costmap, they just consume the data from a fully updated costmap. Thus, if your sensor is not marking the costmap, the readings won't be used used by the planners of move_base.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0